# Ember-Data store.filter with async relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working on a survey application and we are using an existing API. Our models look like:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  participations: DS.hasMany('participation', {async: true})
});

App.Participation = DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
  survey: DS.belongsTo('survey', {async: true}),
  hasCompleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
  hasAccepted: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Survey = DS.Model.extend({
  participations: DS.hasMany('participation', {async: true}),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  locked: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

I would like to return a live record array from my model hook via `store.filter` however this filter needs to deal with both survey's and the async participant record for the current user. How can I handle the async relation resolution in my filter callback function?

```
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      user: this.store.find('user', 1),
      surveys: this.store.filter('survey', {}, function(survey) {
        return !survey.get('locked'); //How do I get the participation record for the current user for the current poll so I can also filter out the completed true
      })
    });
  }
```

If using a live record array of survey's is not the best way to deal with this what is?

Edit:
I've updated the approach to try:

```
App.SurveysRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      user: this.store.find('user', 1),
      all: this.store.find('survey'),
      locked: this.store.filter('survey', function(survey) {
        return survey.get('locked');
      }),
      completed: this.store.filter('participation', {user: 1}, function(participation) {
        return participation.get('hasCompleted');
      }),
      outstanding: this.store.filter('participation', {user: 1}, function(participation) {
        return !participation.get('hasCompleted') && !participation.get('poll.locked');
      })
    });
  }
});
App.SurveysCompletedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('surveys').completed.mapBy('survey');
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/vowuvo/3/edit?html,js,output

However, does the usage of the async property `participation.get('poll.locked')` in my filter pose a potential problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had originally written my response in ES6 and ember-cli format, while localising Ember references... please excuse if this is a touch basic as I reverted it to ES5 and used commonly understood code structure for Ember.

Try this:

```
// beforeModel() and model() are skipped if coming from a collection
// ie: from '/users' to '/users/1'
// setting this up is purely for direct linking to this route's path.
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('user', params.id).then(function(user) {
        return user.get('participations');
    });
},

// only fired once! 
// soon to be obsolete...
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);

    var store  = this.store,
        userId, availSurveys, completed, outstanding;

    store  = this.store;
    userId = model.get('id');

    // this is a promise!
    // also, these filters can be applied elsewhere that Store is available!
    availSurveys = store.filter(
        // modelName to be filtered.
                    'surveys',
        // this part is the query - sent as a request to server, not used as a filter 
                    { locked: false },
        // this is the active filter that will be applied to all survey records in client, 
        // updating 'availSurveys' as the records change
                    function(survey) {
                        return !survey.get('locked');
                    });

    completed = store.filter('participation', 
                    { 
                        user         : userId,
                        hasCompleted : true
                    }, 
                    function(participation) {
                        return participation.get('hasCompleted');
                    });

    outstanding = store.filter('participation', 
                    { 
                        user         : userId,
                        hasCompleted : false,
                        survey       : { locked: false }
                    }, 
                    function(participation) {
                        // this is also a promise!
                        return participation.get('survey').then(function(survery) {
                            return !participation.get('hasCompleted') && !survey.get('locked');
                        });
                    });

    // alternatively, hashSettled waits until all promises in hash have resolved before continuing
    Ember.RSVP.hash({
        availSurveys : availSurveys,
        completed    : completed,
        outstanding  : outstanding
    }).then(function(hash) {
        controller.set('availSurveys', hash.availSurveys);
        controller.set('completed',    hash.completed);
        controller.set('outstanding',  hash.outstanding);
    });
}
```